# How to approximate coordinates basing on azimuths?

Tags: geometry, geospatial, computational-geometry, turfjs

Suppose I have a series of (imperfect) azimuth readouts, giving me vague angles between a number of points. Lines projected from points A, B, C obviously [-don't-always-] *never* converge in a single point to define the location of point D. Hence, angles as viewed from A, B and C need to be adjusted.

To make it more fun, I might be more certain of the relative positions of specific points (suppose I locate them on a satellite image, or I know for a fact they are oriented perfectly north-south), so I might want to use that certainty in my calculations and NOT adjust certain angles at all.

By what technique should I average the resulting coordinates, to achieve a "mostly accurate" overall shape?

I considered treating the difference between non-adjusted and adjusted angles as "tension" and trying to "relieve" it in subsequent passes, but that approach gives priority to points calculated earlier.

Another approach could be to calculate the total "tension" in the set, then shake all angles by a random amount, see if that resulted in less tension, and repeat for possibly improved results, trying to evolve a possibly better solution.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you have a bunch of unknown points (p[] say) and a number of measurements of azimuths, say Az[i,j] of p[j] from p[i]. You want to find the coordinates of the points.

You'll need to fix one point. This is because if the values of p[] is a solution -- i.e. gave the measured azimuths -- so too is q[] where for some fixed x,

```
q[i] = p[i] + x
```

I'll suppose you fix p[0].

You'll also need to fix a distance. This is because if p[] is a solution, so too is q[] where now for some fixed s,

```
q[i] = p[0] + s*(p[i] - p[0])
```

I'll suppose you fix dist(p[0], p[1]), and that there is and azimuth Az[1,2]. You'd be best to choose p[0] p[1] so that there is a reliable azimuth between them. Then we can compute p[1].

The usual way to approach such problems is least squares. That is we seek p[] to minimise

```
    Sum square( (Az[i,j] - Azimuth( p[i], p[j]))/S[i,j])
where Az[i,j] is your measurement data
      Azimuth( r, s) is the function that gives the azimuth of the point s from the point r
      S[i,j] is the 'sd' of the measurement A[i,j] -- the higher the sd of a particular observation is, relative to the others, the less it affects the final result.
```

The above is a non linear least squares problem. There are many solvers available for this, but generally speaking as well as providing the data -- the Az[] and the S[] -- and the observation model -- the Azimuth function -- you need to provide an initial estimate of the state -- the values sought, in your case p[2] ..
It is highly likely that if your initial estimate is wrong the solver will fail.

One way to find this estimate would be to start with a set K of known point indices and seek to expand it. You would start with K being {0,1}. Then look for points that have as many azimuths as possible to points in K, and for such points estimate geometrically their position from the known points and the azimuths, and add them to K. If at the end you have all the points in K, then you can go on to the least squares. If it isn't its possible that a different pair of initial fixed points might do better, or maybe you are stuck.

The latter case is a real possibility. For example suppose you had points p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3] and azimuths A[0,1], A[1,2], A[1,3], A[2,3].
As above we fix the positions of p[0] and p[1]. But we can't compute positions of p[2] and p[3] because we do not know the distances of 2 or 3 from 1. The 1,2,3 triangle could be scaled arbitrarily and still give the same azimuths.

Comment: I understand the need for fixing p[0] and p[1], and minimizing extreme differences between values observed and actual. What I don't understand is the "S" - is this the value for which I'd be computing the coordinates of all the points, giving each Az[n] a different "strength" to affect the outcome?

Comment: Also: the "random shake" I described (calculate all p[], calculate the sum of azimuth-observed-vs-azimuth-calculated squares as Q, apply random noise to p[], again calculate Q, repeat until sufficiently low Q is found) - would it work, at least for simple sets of no more than 20, 30 points? Or should I look into more heuristic solutions?